# Executing a mysql query in regular interval?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to execute a query in regular interval?

Ex: I want a mysql query to be executed every 20 minutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably use a cron job which schedules a task (Google cron jobs), and that can execute and run a MySQL Query on an interval